# Ajax Autocomplete for JQuery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

SOLVED, ERROR IN THE JAVASCRIPT-FILE

I'm trying to get a very simple autocomplete test page to work, using
http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

The source code I that can't get to work looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/test.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

    <script>
        var options, a;
        jQuery(function(){
          options = {lookup:['Jan', 'Feb']};
          a = $('#query').autocomplete(options);
            });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="q" id="query" /> 


</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can write auto complete function in docment.ready

Comment: `jQuery(function(){})` is shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

j is lower case in jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){
```

not

```
JQuery(function(){
```

The rest of code has no problem i think. Anyway, try use some developing tools in order to debug your javascript codes. Something like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), or new [Firefox's built-in development tools](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/08/new-firefox-command-line-helps-you-develop-faster/).(almost every modern browsers has such feature)

Another thing you can try is to write this code in document.ready function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: thanks! still doesn't work though...

Comment: did you check path of javascripts/jquery.autocomplete.js ? exists there ? and loaded successfully ? it works for me in firefox anyway.

Comment: @user1612947 I edited my answer. Take a look at it.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.autocomplete.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'

Comment: @user1612947 I really think your file have a problem. try download it again. put it in a folder with exact folder name javascripts (sometime we missed an 's' at the end of folder name). Because it works for me in firefox 17.0 beta. What's your browser ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Something was indeed wrong with the javascript-file I was using.

Comment: @user1612947 its good to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     var options, a;
>     JQuery(function(){
>       options = {lookup:['Jan', 'Feb']};
>       a = $('#query').autocomplete(options);
>         });
> ```

can you try this-

```
a = $('#query').autocomplete(options.lookup);
```

Comment: tried with no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try code bellow:

```
$(function(){
   var options = {lookup:['Jan', 'Feb']};
   $('#query').autocomplete(options);
});
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JhtNz/

Comment: thanks! tried it, but still not working

Comment: have you look at demo? and what error message you get? try use firebug to do javascript debugging

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic JQUeryUI sample : http://jsfiddle.net/yYLxB/

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});​
```

Comment: He's not using jQueryUI Autocomplete, he's using a different autocomplete widget at the URL in his question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `jQuery` instead of `JQuery`.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/2ZKRR/